No battery charging on Dodge Stratus 2003
I have a Dodge Stratus 2003 Sedan 2.4 Litre. The battery is not charging. Things we have done so far:

Replaced alternator
Replaced battery
Replaced a related engine computer (assumably the PCM, but this wasn’t me)
Replaced ASD relay
Checked if new alternator was bad, triple passed bench test

The alternator is connected to the battery (I can read ~12.X Volts battery voltage on it when the car is off and there is continuity from it’s red lead and it’s body to the positive and negative battery terminals respectively), but it’s just not generating power (it should be ~13.X Volts). I guessed this problem might be the ambient temperature sensor near the battery going haywire, but I checked the OBD II data and the two temperature sensors I could find in there (without knowing which was what) both showed realistic values (84° and 78° as I recall, and the engine had just been running). I want to do continuity tests on the wiring, but I was unable to find a wiring diagram of the charging system: Sadly, this year and version seem to be one of the few that do not have a charging system wiring diagram for them in the Haynes repair manual I bought from AutoZone. Do you have any suggestions for further repairs or tests, or other sources of knowledge on the subject?

Have you had the alternator checked? Wouldn't be the first time a "new" (or rebuilt) alternator was bad straight out of the box.

No, I haven’t. I guess we should do that, but is it possible for me to do it myself? I have a bit of electric gear and it’s very important that this be done as soon as possible.

You can check the voltage at the battery with the engine running. If charging correctly, it would be at ~13.5-14.1vdc. If you're not seeing a charge occuring, then you need to have the alternator checked off the vehicle by a machine, which can usually be done at parts stores (at least here in the States).

I meant to make clear that it is not 13.5V, only 12 odd Volts. I guess I have to get it checked at a shop then.

Tested it, it’s fine.

Here's a wiring diagram from a google search for '04 Dodge Stratus. 

It’s incorrect. There are only three wires connected to the generator: The power lead and a two pin plug. I’m sure because I took it out of the car.

My bad. Edited with a different wiring diagram. Does that help?

Ooh, now this one looks plausible. But, it is definitely an ‘03 vehicle. I guess I can try doing continuity tests anyway. I wish I was more sure.

You can search online as well or better than I can since you need info for advanced troubleshooting. Some models share one circuit for years, not redesigning the 'wheel' unless better technology improves efficiency.
Original alternators with built in voltage regulators only needed two wires; main battery power and signal wire to the battery light. The correct(?) diagram suggests to me the beginnings of smart charging, using the ecm to regulate/fine tune alternator output. My '24 Subaru has smart charging; I monitored voltages at every level; standby, driving, before shutdown. Very strange.

I honestly have no idea how you found what you did already. I tried to find it online and failed, which is why I bought the Haynes manual which still didn’t have it. This is one of the reasons why I hate working on vehicle electronics, the first being that the circuits never make any sense.

Ok, try identifying wiring color to terminals; red power wire to standalone side terminal, pin-1/black w/tan stripe, pin-2 dark green(DG?). if wire colors match, you should be able to perform continuity tests. If incorrect wire colors, I'll try searching again.

The colors match up, and the wire from the alternator to the PCM is continuous. The other wire BK/TN is not grounded like the diagram seems to say it should be. Am I reading that right? Could this be it?

Yes, BK/TAN should be the ground connection. You may have found the problem, the BK/TAN wire not electrically grounded. Terminal damage,, internal wire break without visible evidence from damaged insulation, etc.

Any idea where the black/tan wire is grounded or rather supposed to be? I’d rather not go taking apart the entire wire harness to find the other end of it.

Ground between alternator to chassis/engine should have zero resistance (short). A T pin to stick into the wire connected to one probe with the other probe connected to bare metal chassis or engine block, probing along the insulation until you find the wire break or make a temporary ground connection from the connector to ground and see if the battery voltage jumps up to 14v+ on engine startup. For safety, an inline fuse of 1-5 amp should be part of this temporary ground connection. If you do get charging voltage back up to 14v+, make a new ground connection, without the fuse.

I patched in an artificial ground, and I got charge voltage, so the wire is definitely broken somewhere. I just want to know where the other end of it is as it goes into a wire harness that branches everywhere behind black sleeves. I suspect it is broken at one end rather than somewhere in the middle.

My guess is end terminal corrosion, broken, damaged crimp. GM bundles ground wires in several places, terminating into a splice pack of black wires in a black or gray rectangular cover with a large (10 gauge?) ring terminal. This mounts to ground studs on the chassis. If you examine the engine bay, Dodge may have similar ground splice packs attached to the chassis. The alternator ground wire should be in these packs. Tug firmly on each wire to see if one breaks off. Or just run a new ground wire.

When replacing the alternator, overtightening the battery cable to the alternator post can break the internal wire, rendering the alternator inoperative. Less than hand tight is all that's needed. The side post, if observed, can be seen to turn if overtightening occurs with immediate damage. 

I did more than hand tighten it, as it was loose when I found it, but I didn’t crank it so hard that the post moved.

I removed the alternator and had it tested, it’s fine.

Great! Glad the alternator tested fine. You'll probably need to examine both red and black battery cables, at their battery connections and main negative grounds. If there's corrosion on battery terminals, blush white powder, it's dried battery acid from older vented batteries and can eat copper wires under the heavy insulation on terminals. Some have to peel or cut away insulation to see severe wire corrosion, missing copper, loose crimped cable terminals. A tooth brush with warm water solution of baking soda will dissolve dried battery residue by bubbling immediately and neutralizing acid. Water rinse. Grease battery terminals after cleaning. Main negative cable(s) may be from battery to chassis, then chassis to engine block. Look for how and where your negative battery cable is routed to ensure battery negative connections at chassis and engine block. Red cable is split; one towards engine fuse panel and continuing on to the starter and alternator. This is basic main battery cable wiring virtually universal to all cars, trucks and suvs without needing wiring diagrams.

I am getting non-charger full battery voltage at the alternator whether the car is running or not. Dirty battery leads would not explain this. Unmentioned: The leads are relatively clean and greased. The car starts just fine.
